# Typesafe RPC shared between client/server but with REST methods

Tags: scala

I would like to know if there is a way to join RPC(so client know what he can call and server know what should he respond to) and HTTP Rest(so any other client, without shared codebase can make a call).

There is a lot of http libraries for scala(`akka-http`, `http4s`, etc.) and there is good RPC lib `autowire`. But I see no way to connect them. I know `autowire` is protocol agnostic, but it's a drawback here, because i would like to routing happened in http layer(e.g `akka-http`), not rpc(`autowire`).

I would like to know if it possible. If it is, is there any implementation ongoing?

Comment: Looks like TW got something underway https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/akka-http-rpc/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/thoughtworks/akka/http/RpcSupport.scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[endpoints](https://github.com/julienrf/endpoints) is a work in progress in this direction (note: I am the author of this library). It provides means of defining an API made of HTTP endpoints (which verb, URL, etc. to use), and then it provides implementations that use such APIs as a client or as a server. It is compatible with Scala.js, so you can share your API definition between the client side and the server side of your application and benefit from statically type checked remote calls.

It is designed to give you full control over the usage of HTTP features (e.g. caching, headers, authentication, etc.).

Here is a basic API definition with two endpoints:

```scala
// POST /my-resources
val create: Endpoint[CreateMyResource, MyResource] =
  endpoint(post(path / "my-resources", jsonRequest[CreateMyResource]), jsonResponse[MyResource])

// GET /my-resources/:id
val read: Endpoint[String, Option[MyResource]] =
  endpoint(get(path / "my-resources" / segment[String]), option(jsonResponse[MyResource]))
```

You can then use it as follows from the client-side, to perform an actual call:

```scala
val eventuallyResource: Future[MyResource] =
  create(CreateMyResource("foo", 42))

val eventuallyResource2: Future[Option[MyResource]] =
  read("abc123")
```